# Play 2.6 Database : always getting JDBC connection closed

Tags: java, scala, jdbc, playframework-2.0

I'm using Play 2.6.3 with Postgres and trying to fetch connection from Play.db.Database asynchrounously. Here is the code :

```
public static CompletionStage<Connection> getConnection(Database database, boolean readOnly,
    DatabaseExecutionContext executionContext) {
return supplyAsync(() -> {
    return database.withTransaction(connection -> {
        try {
            return connection;  // checked here and found it's a non-closed connection
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new SQLException("Could not get JDBC Connection", e);
        }
    });
}, executionContext);
```

}

However, whenever I'm trying to use the connection from the dao layer I'm always getting already closed connection although in the above method I'm getting a non-closed connection. Here is the code:

```
DBUtil.getConnection(db, true, executionContext).thenApplyAsync(c -> {
        try {
            System.out.println("closed : " + c.isClosed());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        DBUtil.releaseConnection(c);
        return "";
    });
```

Am I doing something wrong in here?

Comment: There is a misunderstand of what is a loan pattern, like `withTransaction` or `withDB`. The ressources (DB, transaction) are automatically released by the higher kinded function once the function passed as argument is applied. So passing a function returning such managed resource is pointless.

Comment: @cchantep True....However I tried with db.getConnection also and found same result :(

Comment: @cchantep is there any alternate way to do it in the above way?

Comment: First read the documentation